# Unexpected results for checking if a character is a symbol

Tags: c#, .net, string, char

I am creating a string extension to check if a string is all symbols or not however it is not working as I would expect it to, so far I have the following:

```
// Class for: String extensions
public static class StringExtension
{
    // Method for: Determining if a string contains only symbols
    public static bool ContainsOnlySymbols(this String inputString)
    {
        // Identifiers used are:
        bool containsMore = false;

        // Go through the characters of the input string checking for symbols
        foreach (char character in inputString.ToCharArray())
        {
            // This line needs || Char.IsPunctuation(character) also 
            // Credit: @asantaballa
            containsMore = Char.IsSymbol(character) ? false : true;
            if (containsMore)
            {
                return containsMore;
            }
        }

        // Return the results
        return containsMore; // Edited after answer: <-- mistake here
    }
}
```

Now if I use this extension on the following two strings I get the opposite of what I expect to see:

```
string testString = "!=";
```

I expect this to be all symbols, but

```
I expect: testString.ContainsOnlySymbols() => true
I get:    testString.ContainsOnlySymbols() => false
```

Now if I use the next test string:

```
string testString = "Starts with";
```

I expect this to have no symbols

```
I expect: testString.ContainsOnlySymbols() => false
I get:    testString.ContainsOnlySymbols() => true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple problems:

In your loop, you are really only getting the option related to the last character.  And or clause should take care of it.

```
containsMore = containsMore || !(Char.IsSymbol(character) || Char.IsPunctuation(character));
```

Then, you need a not at the end.  If it doesn't contain more, then its only symbols

```
return ! containsMore;
```

You might want a special case for how to handle empty strings too.  Not sure how you want to handle that.  That will be your choice if an empty string should return true or false.

You can accomplish this with a one-liner.  See these examples.

```
        string x = "@#=";
        string z = "1234";
        string w = "1234@";

        bool b = Array.TrueForAll(x.ToCharArray(), y => (Char.IsSymbol(y) || Char.IsPunctuation(y))); // true
        bool c = Array.TrueForAll(z.ToCharArray(), y => (Char.IsSymbol(y) || Char.IsPunctuation(y))); // false
        bool e = Array.TrueForAll(w.ToCharArray(), y => (Char.IsSymbol(y) || Char.IsPunctuation(y))); // false
```

Comment: Yes, this is right, I made a stupid mistake and forgot return !containsMore, I realized this but saw you put it as the answer so thanks

Comment: @G.LC I don't think "!=" will return true for you with this answer... Look at my anwser

Comment: What I ended up doing to fix that was just use @asantaballa's answer with the Char.Punction piece, I will update my question to show this

Comment: ok..i updated the answer accordingly...i have to fix it...fixed

Answer (score 1):

Checking all chars if all isSymbol or Punctuation. we return true here.

```
public static bool ContainsOnlySymbols(this String inputString)
{
    return inputString.ToCharArray().All(x => Char.IsSymbol(x) || Char.IsPunctuation(x));   
}
```

Test:

```
string testString = "Starts with"; // => false
string testString = "!="; // => true
string testString = "@@"; // => true
string testString = "!Starts with"; // => false
```

Comment: Whoops I forgot that part that in my question, it still does not work, I edit my question

Comment: Yeah Ill try it, give me a sec

Comment: I did try that before when debugging actually, but to me that is unexpected since if the character is a symbol then Char.IsSymbol(character) gives true which means contains more should be false, right?

Comment: if it found any symbol we return the result. doesnt need to check other chars.

Comment: added Char.IsPunctuation(x) after @asantaballa approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer dude, but I figured it out, ill add an answer, it is an obvious mistake we all missed

Comment: I saw the issue now. we should check as All() instead of Any().

Comment: Calling `ToCharArray` is not necessary here as `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`;

Answer (score 1):

I believe the IsSymbol method checks for a very specific set of character. You may want to do:

```
containsMore = (Char.IsSymbol(character) || Char.IsPunctuation(character)) ? false : true;
```

Wrote a quick program to show results for character and does show symptom. Might even be that all you need for your app is IsPunctuation.

```
33/!: IsSymbol=False, IsPunctuation=True
```

Program

```
using System;

namespace csharptestchis
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
            {
                char ch = (char)i;
                bool isSymbol = Char.IsSymbol(ch);
                bool isPunctuation = Char.IsPunctuation(ch);
                Console.WriteLine($"{i}/{ch}: IsSymbol={isSymbol}, IsPunctuation={isPunctuation} ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok let me check if I can find which symbols it checks for, I thought of this but didn't try it, I'll test it out

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the idea is simple: you loop your `string`, if you meet a character non-symbol, return `false`. Until the end of `string` and you don't meet a character non-symbol. Voilà, return `true`.

```
public static bool ContainsOnlySymbols(string inputString)
{
    // Identifiers used are:
    bool containsMore = false;

    // Go through the characters of the input string checking for symbols
    foreach (char character in inputString)
    {
        containsMore = Char.IsSymbol(character) ? false : true;
        if(!containsMore)
            return false;
    }

    // Return the results
    return true;
}
```

Secondly, there is a problem with your code, `IsSymbol` returns true only if your character is in these groups

> MathSymbol, CurrencySymbol, ModifierSymbol, and OtherSymbol.

And fortunately, `!` don't be in these groups. That means "!=" returns `false`.

So you must include others conditions like:

```
public static bool ContainsOnlySymbols(string inputString)
{
    // Go through the characters of the input string checking for symbols
    return inputString.All(c => Char.IsSymbol(c) || Char.IsPunctuation(c));
}
```

Or you have to write your own method to determine what symbol is acceptable and what is not.

Or if a string doesn't contain digit and letter, it can be considered symbol. You can do

```
public static bool ContainsOnlySymbols(string inputString)
{
    // Go through the characters of the input string checking for symbols
    return !inputString.Any(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
}
```

Comment: Calling `ToCharArray` is not necessary here as `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`;